# After assignment const char* to const char** I have an error

Tags: c, sdl, vulkan

**Here my code:**

```
const char* sdl_extensions;
const char** sdl_extensions_list;
if (!SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(p_window, &sdl_extension_count, &sdl_extensions)) 
{   
    printf("sdl_extension_count = %i\n", sdl_extension_count);
    printf("[ERROR]: SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions _2\n");
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sdl_extension_count; i++)
    {
        printf("sdl_extension_%i = %s\n", i, *(&sdl_extensions + i));
    }

    sdl_extensions_list = &sdl_extensions;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sdl_extension_count; i++)
    {
        printf("sdl_extension_%i = %s\n", i, *(&sdl_extensions + i));
    }
}
```

**and here the output:**

```
sdl_extension_count = 2
sdl_extension_0 = VK_KHR_surface
sdl_extension_1 = VK_KHR_xlib_surface
sdl_extension_0 = VK_KHR_surface
sdl_extension_1 = diz?�
```

Why after line "**sdl_extensions_list = &sdl_extensions;**" do I have wrong output (**sdl_extension_1 = diz?�**)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading [the `SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions` documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions) what you need to pass is an array of pointers to `SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions`, and then the function initializes those pointers.

The example in the above documentation also shows that you need to call `SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions` *twice*: First to get the element count; Then again after you created your array to get the actual list.

In C the code to do it would be something like this:

```
unsigned int count;
SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(window, &count, NULL);

const char **extensions = malloc(sizeof(const char *) * count);

SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(window, &count, extensions);

for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    printf("Extension %zu: %s\n", i, extensions[i]);
}
```

<sub>[Important note: Error handling is left as an exercise to the reader]</sub>

Remember to `free` the memory you `malloc` after you're done with it.

---

To explain the difference between `&sdl_extensions` in your code and `extensions` in my example, lets draw them and see their difference.

First `sdl_extensions` and the pointer `&sdl_extensions`:

```
+-----------------+      +----------------+
| &sdl_extensions | ---> | sdl_extensions |
+-----------------+      +----------------+
```

Then `extensions` from my example (assuming a `count` of `2`):

```
+------------+      +---------------+---------------+
| extensions | ---> | extensions[0] | extensions[1] |
+------------+      +---------------+---------------+
```

From these two images it's easy to see a major problem here: `&sdl_extensions` points to a *single* `const char *` "element", while `extensions` point to an array of *two* elements.

Because `SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions` treats the argument as a pointer to the first element of an array containing `count` pointers, your code will cause `SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions` to write out of bounds of your single-element "array", which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm very interested what happens when I take an adress from const char*?

Comment: @andkot *Undefined behavior*. The pointer you get with e.g. `&sdl_extensions` (from the code shown in the question) is essentially a pointer to the first element of an array of only a *single* element.

Comment: Thanks @dude but here is the [link](https://photos.google.com/u/1/photo/AF1QipPm4CocrJ5fPAjQpGfdvm2j7P1mbxxQwlPaQiI9) how I understand it. I don't understand why it is Undefined behavior. Because when I get an adress via &sdl_extensions I change nothing.

Comment: @andkot Updated my answer, hopefully you understand the difference a little better, and why your version is wrong and leads to UB.